# ImportError: No module named win32api, python, even when location of win32api is appended to path

Tags: python, importerror

I'm fairly new to python. (Python 2.6)

I'm trying to list the running processes by importing the wmi module.

```
import wmi
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\isapi\test\build\bdis.win32\winexe\temp')
c = wmi.WMI () 
for process in c.Win32_Process ():
    print process.ProcessId, process.Name
```

A system search pointed to win32api being found at the location in the append statement in the code above. But I still get the error: ImportError: No module named win32api

The actual error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\Desktop\Python\Practice Code\file.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wmi
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 88, in <module>
    from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: No module named win32api
```

I've installed win32extensions making sure the versions and platform match. I'm using 2.6
I've also installed wmi-1.4.6

My path:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\Desktop\Python\Practice Code
C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib
C:\WINDOWS\system32\python26.zip
C:\Python26\DLLs
C:\Python26\lib
C:\Python26\lib\plat-win
C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python26
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have all the information you need:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2003-December/001482.html

No need to for WMI, just use Win32 Extensions.

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')

#List all processes
processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')
for process in processes:
    print process.Properties_('Name')

#Get a specific process
p = WMI.ExecQuery('select * from Win32_Process where Name="chrome.exe"')
#view all possible properties
for prop in p[0].Properties_:
    print prop
#print out PID
print p[0].Properties_('ProcessId').Value
```

Peter

Comment: Hi Peter! Thanks for your reply. Besides getting the job done, I'm also wondering I can get past the import error.

Comment: Also, your code snippet gives me an import error that No module named win32com.client was found.

Comment: if you are getting an import error I suspect your win32extensions may not be installed correctly - which may be the root of your problems.

Comment: have you tried installing your python etc using the ActiveState bundled package ? check out www.activestate.com

Comment: I suspected that too, so I reinstalled win32extensions but to no avail. I will try the ActiveState's package now and get back.

Comment: Reinstalling with ActiveState did fix the problem, although I had to install the wmi seperately. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Have to say, not using WMI speeds things up quite a bit. I guess I will stick to just using the win32extensions. Thanks for the link Peter.